# Ecommerce, storing ordered products with product options

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, e-commerce

I'm trying to settle on the best way to store an order within the database.

Each product can be configured, and not all options are the same. For example:

```
Product A
Size: small, medium, large
Membership: 1 year, 2 years, 3 years, 5 years

Product B
Size: small, medium

Product C
Design: a, b, c, d
Recipient: jondoe@msn.ca
Amount: 25.99
```

As you can see, each order can contain some pretty variable data. What would be the best way to deal with storing this kind of transaction?

Comment: if your in this position i would  consider one oft the many existing E-commerce applications.

Comment: every well developed, well supported, well tested, e-commerce app is customisable.

Comment: You're missing the point. I'm not using any third party applications for this, period.

Comment: well my point is , that if your asking that, you should be, good luck.

Comment: Really not helpful. I'm trying to learn... hence the question. If I knew the answer, why would I post the question in the first place?

Comment: IMHO e-commerce is not the place to learn, when dealing with money, you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: I appreciate what you're trying to say, but if I avoid learning how to properly structure an e-commerce schema, when will I ever have a chance to learn? That doesn't makes sense to me. At some point, I have to learn this side of things.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the tables you're going to have I would do

```
Products
product_id
product_name

Sizes
size_id
size_name

Memberships
membership_id
membership_name

Designs
design_id
design_name

Recipients
recipient_id
recipient_name

Orders
order_id
product_id
size_id
design_id
membership_id
recipient_id
total_amount
```

Depending how your amounts are going to be calculated you could add an amount to each table as 'amount' for products, sizes, etc and then in the final Orders section pull the amount from each type and calculate it to update a 'total_amount' column in the final order.  If they change size_id have it re-calculate, etc.

Hope this helps?

Comment: This is too specific. Originally, I was just going to have an `order_details` table that just contained the `order_id` and a serialized data column for the product attributes... I just feel that's too messy.

Comment: It's more messy using 1 table then 5.